# Weird behavior of Background worker and multiple progress bar c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

i try to simulate a bit long running process. in my app i use Background and add progress bar dynamically. when i click on start button then a process start and a progress bar added on panel. if i just click once then everything works fine but if i click twice or more then that number of progress bar getting added but the last progress bar progress are incremented and at last other progress bar progress incremented suddenly.

i want whatever number of progress bars are added all should process simultaneously not last one first and first one last. all should go together like many process are running simultaneously in their own context. here is my code and i hope if some one look at it then they can understand where is the flaw. please help me fix the flaw for which last added progress bar progress incremented. if possible run my code and see the problem.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    MyBackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = null;
    Dictionary<string, string> dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1 = new MyBackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;   
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(txtNumber.Text);

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string strID = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss")+DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
        MyBackgroundWorker tmpBg = (sender as MyBackgroundWorker);
        tmpBg.Name = "bg_" + strID;

        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
        pb.Minimum = 0;
        pb.Maximum = 100;
        pb.Name = "pb_" + strID;
        pb.Width = txtNumber.Width;
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        });

        dct.Add(tmpBg.Name, pb.Name);

        int input = int.Parse(e.Argument.ToString());
        for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress bar. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyBackgroundWorker tmpBg = (sender as MyBackgroundWorker);
        string strName = tmpBg.Name;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strName))
        {
            strName = strName.Substring(3);
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find(("pb_" + strName), true)[0];
            pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyBackgroundWorker tmpBg = (sender as MyBackgroundWorker);
        string strName = tmpBg.Name;
        strName = strName.Substring(3);
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find(("pb_" + strName), true)[0];
        pb.Value = 100;
        //MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }

}

    public class MyBackgroundWorker : System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        {
            public MyBackgroundWorker()
            {
            }

            public MyBackgroundWorker(string name)
            {
                Name = name;
            }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

### UPDATE Portion

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyBackgroundWorker tmpBg = (sender as MyBackgroundWorker);
            string strName = tmpBg.Name;
            strName = strName.Substring(3);
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find(("pb_" + strName), true)[0];
            //pb.Value = 100;
            //MessageBox.Show("Done");
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(pb);
        }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't add the event handlers to the background worker when you click on the button. Or at least check if it's null and add on that case. Try adding them in `Form2_Load` rather than `btnStart_Click`

Comment: yes i did the whole background worker related code i move to form_load. i just call RunWorkerAsync(txtNumber.Text); from btnstart_click event when i first time click then it is ok the moment i click next time i got error "This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently." i want to click N number of time on button and there should not be any problem and that is why i create a new instance of BackgroundWorker every time from button_click event. have any suggestion to change the code which enable me to click on button N number of time without any error.

Comment: sorry about that, I misunderstood what you were doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working how you want it to.

1. In ProgressChanged, I get the progressbar another way.
2. In DoWork, I report progress as a percentage and from the current backgroundWorker.
3. I removed `Thread.Sleep` because I think it was causing problems, added `Console.WriteLine`  in `DoWork` to slow down program (otherwise it's faster than the `ProgressBar` renders)

   ```
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
       MyBackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = null;
       Dictionary<string, string> dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       public Form2()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }

       private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           backgroundWorker1 = new MyBackgroundWorker();
           backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
           backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
           backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
           backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
           backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(int.Parse(txtNumber.Text));

       }

       private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {
           string strID = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
           MyBackgroundWorker tmpBg = (sender as MyBackgroundWorker);
           tmpBg.Name = "bg_" + strID;

           ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
           pb.Minimum = 0;
           pb.Maximum = 100;
           pb.Name = "pb_" + strID;
           pb.Width = txtNumber.Width;
           this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
           {
               flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
           });

           dct.Add(tmpBg.Name, pb.Name);

           int input = (int)e.Argument;
           for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(tmpBg.Name + ": " + (i * 100 / input));   //for testing (this line slows the program down a lot)
               tmpBg.ReportProgress(i * 100 / input);
               if (tmpBg.CancellationPending)
               {
                   e.Cancel = true;
                   return;
               }
           }
       }

       // This event handler updates the progress bar. 
       private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           MyBackgroundWorker tmpBg = (sender as MyBackgroundWorker);
           string strName = tmpBg.Name.Substring(3);
           ProgressBar pb;

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strName))
           {
               foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
               {
                   if (c.Name == ("pb_" + strName))
                   {
                       pb = (ProgressBar)c;
                       pb.Value = Math.Min(100,e.ProgressPercentage);
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       {
           MyBackgroundWorker tmpBg = (sender as MyBackgroundWorker);
           string strName = tmpBg.Name;
           strName = strName.Substring(3);
           ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find(("pb_" + strName), true)[0];
           pb.Value = 100;
           //MessageBox.Show("Done");
       }

   }

   public class MyBackgroundWorker : System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
   {
       public MyBackgroundWorker()
       {
       }

       public MyBackgroundWorker(string name)
       {
           Name = name;
       }

       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but some time this line                 ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find(("pb_" + strName), true)[0];
throw index out of exception when i add too many progress bar clicking on button so fast. how to fix it?

Comment: I'm currently working on an edit that should fix some more things I found

Comment: we know that RunWorkerCompleted event fire when backgroundWorker1 done the job. so from there i try to remove progress bar dynamically and seen that before updating progress bar fully the progress bar is getting removed. can u please have a look at my RunWorkerCompleted event. thanks

Comment: i saw there is problem many people face to update progress bar fully. in win 7 progress bar is very slow but i got no fix. so if u have any trick to show the progress bar with full green part and then remove after few sec.

Comment: Yeah, I had that problem as well. The only solution I can think of for that is to create a timer, name it based on the background worker and start it when the background worker finishes. In the tick event find the progress bar by the timer name and then remove it. Have the timer wait like 2 seconds. Timer doesn't seem to have an editable `Name` field. You may have to do with it what you did with the BackgroundWorker